# Issues with ARP and sending data

Tags: c, udp, arp

I am writing some code for a university assignment (in C / using visual studios) that we will be running on a server in a LAN (a load of bots fighting it out via s host server, using UDP connections).

I am trying to get a couple of "naughty" functions to work, namely an ARP spoofing function and something to send spam data.

I can get the spam data function to work, but only against the server / pc it is connected to, it doesn't affect any of the other clients connected to it (which is what I am aiming for).

The arp spoofer just won't work at all, I keep getting errors saying it can't find the MAC address.

I have added links to my code below (as I am unsure what the policy is for more risqué code, so figured using codeshare the link will expire after 14 days anyway).

https://codeshare.io/2pAYOV - Spam

https://codeshare.io/aYz6rM - ARP

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, that this is allowed? On many hack-contests manipulating layer 2 is taboo (too lame ;))

Comment: @Ctx - Yeah, it is even awarded, we get bonus points for anything we can implement along these lines.